# How to JSENCODE from an apex controller?

Tags: apex, security-review, xss

I select a list of sObjects in my controller then pass directly to my visualforce page where I render out as a javascript object. I can't use JSENCODE in the visualforce page because I need the serialized object to be rendered as a JS Object. Instead, I think I need to iterate through the values in Apex and make sure they are encoded to protect against XSS. Any recommendations on the proper way to do this?

Controller

```
    recipientList = Database.query('select Id, Name, Email from Contact where AccountId=\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(originObjectIdString) + '\' and Contact.Name!=Null and Contact.Email!=Null');

serializedRecipientOptions =
JSON.serialize(recipientList);
```

VF Page

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var myEscapedObject = {
serializedRecipientOptions: {!
serializedRecipientOptions}
}
</script>
```

I was thinking something like this in the controller code (except this doesn't work because JSENCODE is not defined in the controller)

```
List<sObject> escapedRecipientList = new List<sObject>();
            for(sObject ind_recipient:recipientList){
                ind_recipient.Id = JSENCODE(ind_recipient.Id);
                ind_recipient.Name = JSENCODE(ind_recipient.Name);
                ind_recipient.Email = JSENCODE(ind_recipient.Email);
                escapedRecipientList.push(ind_recipient);
            }
            return escapedRecipientList;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `JSENCODE` in tandem with the built-in `Javascript` method **`JSON.parse`**.

```
var myEscapedObject = JSON.parse("{!JSENCODE(serializedOptions)}");
```

Answer (score 0):

The Apex method [String.escapeEcmaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_escapeEcmaScript) will allow you to escape text using Javascript (EcmaScript) rules.

Comment: Won't security review flag it if you don't escape on the client side, regardless of if you use this method? Just curious.

Comment: I think you may be right regarding security review.